# How can I make a recursive promise with $q

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, timeout, angular-promise

let's say I have this rule:

```
var count = 0;
function isCountFifty() {
  count++;
  return 50 === count;
}
```

I want to perform `isCountFifty()` 50 times and each time put a `$timeout` 0 before the next time I run this method again until it reaches 50 and resolves the promise.

I'm trying to achieve it using angular `$q`

This is the general look:

```
var defer = $q.defer();
 defer.promise.then(resolveWhenFifty())
              .then(function () { ... something to do after count reaches 50 ...});
defer.resolve();
```

I'm trying to figure out what should be here:

```
function resolveWhenFifty () {
  return function () {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    if (isCountFifty()) {
      defer.resolve();
    } else {
      $timeout(function () {
        ... ? WHAT SHOULD BE THE RECURSION HERE ? ...
      }
    }
    return defer.promise;
  }
}
```

I've tried several ways but I keep getting lost on how to make this recursive function that returns the right promises with right resolves, and how do I chain all these promises together.

Comment: This seems like an XY Problem. Is this a learning exercise? If not what is the real use case?

Comment: Call `arguments.callee` if not in strict mode or call the `resolveWhenFifty()` if in strict mode.

Comment: @charlietfl The real usecase: I have a div. I want to add to it class x and only after class x was added I want to add to it class y. This is why I want to check the dom $(element).hasClass(x) { $element.addClass('y') } and I want to put several timeouts (with max counter of 10) to check if x was added and only then add y

Comment: This would be simple if you used  angular methodology .. setting `ng-class` based on data model. Why are you needing to check the DOM instead of using data model to drive what happens in the DOM? Show some more code that is used to change the class

Comment: @charlietfl I'm writing a directive that manages animation classes. it needs to put classes in a specific sequence. my assumption that I can't use ng-class because the user of my directive might use it and I don't want to prevent them from doing so. I didn't think there is a difference doing it with ng-class or doing it straight to the DOM but I might not be aware to these nuances. and besides that I'm trying to learn how to work with promises and this is good practice.

Comment: Still not clear how promise would be used. Sounds like a case for a watch. Create simple demo that outlines concept

Comment: @charlietfl I've answered my own question with a demo. I think it can be refactored but it does what I wanted it to do.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to make it work. I made a demo on plunkr.

https://plnkr.co/edit/MQS6n9qKOfGMxYwMQ8H3?p=preview

I should have been more clear that the `isCountFifty()` is just an example for a condition function that will iterate again and again until resolved (with a max number of timeouts).

and I'm attaching the main concept below:

```
  function isCountFifty() {
    count++;
    return 50 === count;
  }

  function delay(time) {
    return function() {
      return $timeout(angular.noop, time);
    }
  }

  function recursion(defer) {
    if (isCountFifty()) {
      defer.resolve();
    } else {
      var newDefer = $q.defer();
      newDefer.promise.then(delay(50)).then(function() {
        recursion(defer);
      });
      newDefer.resolve();
    }
  }

  var defer = $q.defer();

  recursion(defer);

  defer.promise.then(function() {
    console.log('yay! if I see this message it means I made 50 timeouts of 50 ms each');
    return defer.promise;
  });
```

I have a clue that this code can be more efficient but it does what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The code can be re-factored to avoid using `$q.defer`.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myController', function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
  var _this = this;
  var vm = $scope;
  vm.recursions = 0;
  vm.isResolved = false;

  var time = 200;

  function waitForClass(count) {
      if (count>0) { 
        vm.recursions++;
        return $timeout(function(){return waitForClass(count-1)},time);
      } else {
        return $q.when(0);
      }
  }
  waitForClass(50).then(function() {
    vm.isResolved = true;
    return 0;
  });
});
```

The `$timeout` service returns promises and those promises can be **chained**.

Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a **chain** of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)</sup>

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/zG8baJGzxsPUYb2W4Quj?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. Check out [working CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dMyWZe?editors=1112).

You'll get a console output like this:

- 1
- "in timeout"
- 2
- "in timeout"
- 3
- "in timeout"
- ... etc ...
- 49
- "in timeout"
- 50
- "in timeout"
- "done"

  ```
    var self = this;

    this.isCountFifty = function(count) {
      console.log(count);
      return 50 === count;
    }    
    var promises = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 51; i++) promises.push({
      count: i
    });

    // execute each promise synchronously
    var myFunc = function() {
      return promises.reduce(function(promise, item) {          
        return promise.then(function() {
          return $q.when(
            $timeout(function() {
              console.log('in timeout');
            },500),
            self.isCountFifty(item.count));
        });
      }, $q.when());
   };        
   myFunc().then(function() {
     console.log('done');
   });
  ```

Comment: thanks for the response. I should have been more clear that it's not a 50 timeout but a condition that should be checked until resolved (timeouts number is unknown). I've answered my own question - you can see what I meant.